# rgba buffer multiplication (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, multiplication, rgba

I saved the decoded image as RGBA, and stored the pixels into a buffer of type:

```
unsigned char *data1;
```

I have another buffer (the same size 480x720), containing another set of RGBA data.

```
unsigned char *data2;
```

How can I used OpenGL to do point-wise multiplication of these two buffers

e.g.:
If data1 and data2 are:
data1 = (a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,...)

data2 = (b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,...)

Then how to use OpenGL to do the following?

data1*data2 = (a0*b0,a1*b1,a2*b2,a3*b3,a4*b4,...)

Is it possible to do this operation using OpenGL?

Comment: It would be nice to know what you are trying to do. You can load them both as textures and map them to a quad, use shaders to multiply them, and then render to texture ... but it really depends on what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: @StephanvandenHeuvel: I am developing a DSP algorithm to do eye detection. So, I would need to do plenty of hefty matrix computations. But can someone please provide a sample code how to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a heavy openGL user, so I can't speak to what it can and cannot do, but I might suggest that you look at OpenCV for what you're trying to achieve. There are quite a few canned pupil tracking examples available using OpenCV, and there are some really nice guides getting openCV compiled on embedded devices, like Beagleboard, and Rasp Pi.

I think of openGL as a drawing tool and openCV as a processing tool.

openCV comes with defined matrix types, and many of the matrix operations you would want to do.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

The simple fragment shader that you can use:

```
in vec2 tex_coords;
uniform sampler2d texture_a, texture_b;
out vec4 my_color;

vec4 a = texture(texture_a, tex_coords);
vec4 b = texture(texture_b, tex_coords);

my_color = vec4(a.r * b.r, a.g * b.g, a.b * b.b, 1.0);
```